# Datatables Server Side Pagination just display 1 Page from total record 535 data

Tags: php, datatables, server-side-rendering

The bInfo say 20 from 535 total entries data, but the pagination just have 1 page:

[image]

there's the code

```
  "serverSide": true,
  scrollY: screen.height * 0.56,
  scrollX: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  order: [
    [0, "asc"]
  ],
  dom: "<'toolbar'>frtip",
  paging: true,
  "pageLength":20,
  ajax: {
    url: "get.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: function(d) {
      d.fabric_id = fabric_menu;
    },
   
  },      
});
```

an anybody explain where the error to me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "_Showing 1 to 20 of 20 entries (filtered from 535 total entries)_". Because you are showing 20 rows per page, then that is 1 page of data - which is why you only see 1 page in the pagination button list. All those other 515 records have been _filtered out_ (according to your server) and are therefore not reachable. So there is nothing "wrong" here.

Comment: If this is not what you expected, then please take a look at what values your server has populated for `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` in the [JSON returned from the server](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data). Specifically, `recordsFiltered` means how many records are visible after the server has filtered the data based on the user-provided search term (if any).